# Is nested ControlTemplate possible? Control Template inside Control Template

Tags: wpf

I want to make two controlTemplate at once and invoke them separately with common properties some.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ProcessTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DecisionTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<!--I want to add like this--> 
<Grid > 
<Path Style="{StaticResource Process}" ToolTip="Process"> 
<ControlTemplate> <Path Style="{StaticResource Process_DragThumb}"/> </ControlTemplate> 
</Path> <Viewbox> </Viewbox> 
</Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

[Code is shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZXTZ.png)

Comment: Could you post your code? Please show us what you tried to do.

Comment: I have tried like this :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZXTZ.png

Comment: I think you should post your code as text, not as an image through editing this question.

Comment: <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProcessTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="DecisionTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"><!--I want to add like this-->
        <Grid >
            <Path Style="{StaticResource Process}" ToolTip="Process">
              
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Path Style="{StaticResource Process_DragThumb}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
           
            </Path>
            <Viewbox>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

Comment: It would help if you explained *why* you want to do this.  There may be a better, more "wpf way", to do what you actually want to accomplish.